# what is this 'now' mean in jquery css function

Tags: jquery

I'm a newbie to jquery, I came across this in jquery api about animate() function. Even though its perfectly working, I just want to know what it mean there and how it can be implemented in some other places. Here is the example code block and urls. Thanks in advance.

```
   step: function( now, fx ){
    $( ".block:gt(0)" ).css( "left", now );
   }
```

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

http://jsbin.com/ihukob/1/edit

Comment: This seems to be part of another code, so paste the whole code to see

Comment: I've given the links to whole code. please see the jsbin link.

Comment: In the documentation you linked, `now` is clearly defined as: `now: the numeric value of the property being animated at each step`.  So, if you're animating opacity from 0 to 1, `now` will be the numeric values that start at 0 and progress to 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code:

```
step: function( now, fx ){
    $( ".block:gt(0)" ).css( "left", now );
}
```

`now` is an argument passed to the function `step`. You are using jquery to set the `left` position of the element to the value passed as argument.

Example:

If you call

```
step("100px", fx);
```

then the code will execute as

```
$( ".block:gt(0)" ).css( "left", "100px" );
```

**Update**

It is the `step` function for `jquery.animate()`. The function will be called for each step of the animation.

> step Type: Function( Number now, PlainObject fx ) A function to be
>   called after each step of the animation.

What happens:

When you are animating `$( ".block:first" )`, you are using the step function to move the other `block` elements to the left also.

**Update 2**

```
now: the numeric value of the property being animated at each step
```

As the code is like this

```
$( ".block:first" ).animate({
   left: 100
}
```

`now` will contain the value of `left` for `.block:first`.

Comment: yes, now is an argument, what will be its value here in current css function?? I found now is a function related to time in jquery api.